# Chef - repeat block of text in template x times

Tags: chef-infra, chef-template

Is there any way to repeat same text block in template X times?
For example, I need to generate template with hosts names and a block of text.

```
Host1
A lot of text
.
.
HostX
A lot of text
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an `each` loop in your template:

```
<%- @hosts.each_with_index do |host, n| -%>
Host<%= n %>
A lot of text involving <%= host %>
etc
etc
<%- end -%>
```

You can use any normal Ruby flow control stuffs in Erb templates.